# resize view to the right height after adding it to a uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, resize

so i've go a uiviewcontroller (with its default view) that i created programmatically like

```
TestViewController *aVC = [[MJImageCropViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:aVC animated:YES];
```

inside it there is something like this in the viewDidLoad

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

the problem is, that the height of the view of the pushedViewController remains 460px but visible is only 416px (because of the existing navigationController.

is there a way to let the uiview of the pushed viewcontroller resize the right way without setting explicit the frame to 416 (because of rotation and so on)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try something like this in `-viewDidLoad:`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Resize view to account for nav bar
    CGFloat navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height - navBarHeight;
    self.view.frame = frame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the view is being resized correctly, but it's subview's autoresizing masks are not set properly. Also, it makes a lot more sense to place the autoresize code you posted either in loadView (if you are creating the view programmatically) or in the XIB file.

Try to log out the view controller's frame at the end of viewDidLoad via

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
```

And see what that tells you.

Comment: i only got two subviews at the moment that does get the exact same auroresizingmask. logging in viewDiDLoad in my pushedViewController gives me `{{0, 20}, {320, 460}}`